# Class vs Class<T> in Java

Tags: java, generics

Is there a difference between these two lines of code? Or is the first line just a shorthand way or writing the second line?

```
Class cls1 = Person.class;
Class<Person> cls2 = Person.class;
```

Comment: The second line is type-safe.

Comment: The first one is type safe too. This line will not compile     Living lv= cls1.newInstance();

Comment: Class is a generic class. Search "raw type" versus "generic type"

Comment: @Foo First line is not type-safe. It will give you warning "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized" and I believe warnings are designed to be handled

Comment: Quick comment over @davidxxx comment: "Raw types refer to using a generic type without specifying a type parameter. For example, List is a raw type, while List<String> is a parameterized type."

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is only significant at compile-time.

`Class<Person>` allows type safety and static type checking. For example, the following code is perfectly understood by the compiler and reduces unnecessary type casts. Additionally, it's type-safe:

```
Class<Person> personClass = Person.class;
Person person = personClass.newInstance(); //Great! Return type is Person
```

However, this same version using the raw `Class` type doesn't give type safety benefits of the above code:

```
Class personClass2 = Person.class;
Person person2 = personClass2.newInstance(); //error
```

The compiler complains about the last statement:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Person

Although it's effectively the same `Class` instance, the generic version allows static type checking, which provides safety and avoids unnecessary type casts.

At runtime, however, the two are basically equivalent.

```
System.out.println(personClass == personClass2); //true
System.out.println(personClass == person.getClass()); //true
```

When used with reflection or otherwise inspected, the two have no difference because the instance is the same and generic types are erased.